# Save Map generator preset

Tags: factorio

Factorio has a large number of settings in the Map generator. And saved Presets.
I'd like to save a preset of my own preferences and it's a feature I do expect.
I have searched the Steam folder for one of the preset names, but can't find any.

How can I store my own map generator preset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no in-game way of doing this currently.

What you CAN do is dig into the games' files to find this: `Factorio/data/base/prototypes/map-gen-presets.lua` . Make a backup copy, then open it in a text editor like Notepad++. You should see text like so:

[image: Sample generator presets text]

Shouldn't be too hard to get your head around, just make sure you keep the formatting the same all the way through. If your game fails to start, restart from the backup copy or rollback some changes, as all the formatting is important.

[Sourced from here.](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=45083)